# Filter keys by value using JMESPATH

Tags: jmespath

I have the following json schema:

```
{
  "id1": "INACTIVE",
  "id2": "ACTIVE",
  "id3": "INACTIVE",
  "id4": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Using jmespath is it possible to write a query to get only the `id`s which have a value of `ACTIVE` like so:

```
["id2", "id4"]
```